# Convert JSON string into apex map

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json, jquery

Assigning JSON string to apex:inputText

jQuery code:

```
$('*[id*=stageName]').val(JSON.stringify(final_array));
```

Apex & Visualforce:

```
 public String stageName{set;get;}
 <apex:inputText value="{!stageName}" id="stageName"/>
```

Getting below text into stageName in apex through jQuery

```
{
    "New":["Prospect","Open","In Negotiation","Final Negotiation"],
    "Readoption":["Won"],
    "Rollover":["Won","Invoiced","Lost"],
    "Upsell":["In Negotiation","Lost"],
    "Conversion":[]
}
```

How to convert this JSON text into apex map like `Map<String,List<String>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like,

```
String jsonInput = '{"New":["Prospect","Open","In Negotiation","Final Negotiation"],"Readoption":["Won"],"Rollover":["Won","Invoiced","Lost"],"Upsell":["In Negotiation","Lost"],"Conversion":[]}';
Map<String,List<String>> m = (Map<String,List<String>>)JSON.deserialize(jsonInput, Map<String,List<String>>.class);
```

Comment: Please review [answer] and provide an explanation to the above.